# Trouble updating records in database using OLEDB

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I am creating a program in which I want to update the password of the admin. I tried the SELECT UPDATE statement but still give me an error. I will show the code snippet behind.

```
Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
Dim selectQuery As String
Dim updateQuery As String

Protected Sub Reset Password
    If txtNewPassword.Text <> txtRepeatPassword.Text Then
        Response.Write(<script>alert('Password dont match!')</script>)
        Response.Write("<script>window.location.reload()</script>")
    Else
        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source = " & Server.MapPath("Point_Of_Sales.mdb"))
            con.Open()
            selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE username = '" & Request.QueryString("userName") & "'"
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(selectQuery, con)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                cmd.Dispose()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source = " & Server.MapPath("Point_Of_Sales.mdb"))
            con.Open()
            updateQuery = "UPDATE Admin SET (password = @repeatNewPass) WHERE (username = @username) "
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(updateQuery, con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repeatNewPass", txtRepeatPassword.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",Request.QueryString("userName")
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
                con.Close()
            End Using
            Response.Write(<script>alert('Successfully updated the password for admin!')</script>)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

-- Here as you can see, I used the Request.QueryString retrieve the values from another page which is the userName. The error that I am encountering is within the second connection that has the UPDATE query. Any help and suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: You're almost there, but "gives me an error" is just about as useful as "doesn't work". What exactly is happening? Is your printer suddenly complaining "PC LOAD LETTER"?

Answer (score 0):

Password is a reserved word, so try:

```
updateQuery = "UPDATE Admin SET ([password] = @repeatNewPass) WHERE (username = @username) "
```

and parameters are just sequenced:

```
updateQuery = "UPDATE Admin SET ([password] = ?) WHERE (username = ?) "
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. I also changed the password column to admin_password and used it in my query but still I encounter an error that UPDATE query has a problem